# How to kill child processes & grandchild processes controlled by supervisor

Tags: python, process, supervisord, gipc

In a process controlled by Supervisor, I fork child process

```python
for i in xrange(MANAGER_PROCESS_NUM):
    p = gipc.start_process(target=daemon_process, args=())
    record.append(p)
for r in record:
    r.join()
```

then in each child process, I create grandchild process:

```python
w = gipc.start_process(target=self._pool_worker, daemon=True)
```

How can I kill all the child processes & grandchild processes when I run 
"supervisorctl stop xxx" to stop my main process?

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options:

1. Modify your Python programs so that when they receive signals like `SIGTERM` they propagate them to the children explicitly.
2. Enable the `supervisord` options `stopasgroup` and `killasgroup`.  These options are [documented](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html) as sending signals to the entire process group rather than just one process.

Comment: I have set the config options: `stopasgroup=true, killasgroup=true`.But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you check (using `ps -f` or so) what the Parent PID of each process is, and what the Process Group ID (PGID) of each process is?  Knowing the full details would really help here.  Also, can you try setting a signal handler in each Python program to print something on `SIGTERM`, and testing with `stopasgroup`?

Comment: OK,I'll try, Thanks so much.